# How can I control output level volumes separately on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio

I have an ASUS M3A78PRO motherboard with realtek 7.1 audio chipset onboard.
I have also two speaker and a subwoofer with no external volume control.
I'm on Windows 7.
There is a way to control, separately from speaker volume, subwoofer volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an easy thing to answer.  We would need to know some details about your "sub-woofer" to be clear.

Most 2.1 speaker sets (left/right + sub) typically do not have a separate `subwoofer` channel, but rather the left and right data are processed together, and there is some electronics in the inside that splits off a `frequency range` from the audio source and then passes that to the sub-woofer.  An easy way to tell is by looking at the plug(s) itself(themselves):

[image: 1/4" Headphone Jack]

You can clearly see that there's only 2 channels.  In this case, the only way to amplify the sub-woofer's volume, is to use an equalizer and amplify the range that the electronics filter out for the subwoofer.  Cheaper speaker systems frequently continue to pass that range onto the left & right speakers, so you'll also be amplifying them.

Some low-grade speaker systems have additional plugs for TRUE 3.1/5.1/7.1 configuration options, where you end up with 2/3 or 4 of those 1/4" jacks.  For example, in basic 3.1 surround sound, you would end up with 1 plug carrying the left and right channels, 1 plug carrying the center and subwoofer channels.  In those cases, you simply turn up the volume on the specified channel.

Higher-end speaker systems, rather than relying on 2,3 or 4 separate plugs will usually offer either an optical interface or digital interface where the channels are carried as a single digital signal and then the receiver interprets the signal and then sends the signal to each speaker.  Their plugs look like this:

[image]

--or--

[image]

Your system, does indeed include a digital S/PDIF port for hooking up to a digital receiver... but I doubt your speakers would support it.  (unless you paid quite a lot for 'em)  The 6 "1/4 inch" jacks on your motherboard can be configured to have 4 of them behaving as audio out, giving you 7.1 audio. (left/right front, left/right mid, left/right back, center and sub)  Usually there's a tool that pops up when you plug something in that asks you what you just plugged in.

Comment: It's a great explanation, but I didn't specified well the configuration. I have two speakers 2.0 (if I can say that) connected to front speaker output (on the mobo). The subwoofer is a single piece, taken from an old 5.1 system, and so is detached from the two speakers. It's connected to the subwoofer output (on the mobo). So the question is: can I select different volumes for different output channels?

Comment: The answer is a "most-likely".  Different drivers behave slightly differently.  Typically, you can find and adjust the levels independently if you right-click the sound-icon in the system tray and select `Playback Devices`, and then select properties of the output device, and finally go to the `Levels` tab.  Sometimes you can only do such adjustments with an application for that sound device.